# url.strip()+' - CatchAllError'

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error

I am try to run this program as it start run but while running it's create error regrading  CatchAllError . I want output as ' Pass ' But its not please help. Thanks

```
if line:
msg = url.strip()+' - CatchAllError'
print msg
with open("log_Error.txt", "a") as log:
log.write(msg+"\n")
else:
pass
```

You can see my whole program at https://ghostbin.com/paste/ypdmd.

You can see that if condition should be pass but it's not. To include target list go to https://ghostbin.com/paste/pjuox and download target list and other information.

Comment: If you get an error, you should *post it here*.

Comment: Also, please don't use irrelevant tags.

Comment: I'm personally surprised you got help at all (good for you!), but in the future please read the help topics and guidelines on how to ask a good question. Posting a giant wall of code with no context and a bit of "Please help it's not doing what I want HALP" doesn't help anyone, including you.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You are mixing tabs and spaces. This confuses Python* and may cause unexpected behavior.

Use only tabs or only spaces, not both. Spaces is preferable.

<sub>(*well, not really. Python knows exactly how to handle tabs; it just does so in a way that is very surprising to most users. In particular, one tab is *not* equivalent to 4 spaces, or 8, or whatever it looks like in your text editor. See [2.1.8 - Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation) for more information.)</sub>

Comment: I have re edited but problem continues. You can get me new code at https://ghostbin.com/paste/ypdmd